# Flutter FutureBuilder wait for database connection in SQFLite

Tags: flutter

I'm using **SQFLite** to store data in the flutter application. The database provider is

```
class MessageDatabaseProvider {
  Database db;

  Future open() async {
    final path = join(await getDatabasesPath(), databaseName);
    db = await openDatabase(
        path,
        version: 1,
        onCreate: (Database db, int version) async {
          await db.execute('''
            create table $tableMessage (
              $columnId integer primary key autoincrement,
              $columnCountryCode text not null,
              $columnPhoneNumber text not null,
              $columnMessage text null,
              $columnCreated integer null)
            ''');
        }
    );
  }

  Future<List<Message>> list() async {
    List<Map> maps = await db.query(tableMessage,
      columns: [columnId, columnCountryCode, columnPhoneNumber, columnMessage, columnCreated],
      orderBy: columnId
    );

    List<Message> list = [];
    maps.forEach((element) {
      list.add(Message.fromMap(element));
    });

    return list;
  }
}
```

and Building a **ListView**

```
class _MessageHistoryListState extends State<MessageHistoryList> {
  final _database = MessageDatabaseProvider();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: _buildMessageHistory(),
    );
  }
  
  Widget _buildMessageHistory() {

    _database.open();
    
    return FutureBuilder<List>(
      future: _getList(),
      initialData: [],
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        print(snapshot);
        return snapshot.hasData ?
          ListView.builder(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, i) {
              return _buildRow(snapshot.data[i]);
            },
          )
        : Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

It shows the list of items the first time, then after changing navigation it gives error

```
AsyncSnapshot<List<dynamic>>(ConnectionState.done, null, NoSuchMethodError: The method 'query' was called on null.
```

Comment: where are u calling `open()`?

Comment: In the `_buildMessageHistory` method

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `openDatabase` until you close it by using the following line

```dart
await db.close();
```

you should call  `_database.open();` from `init()` if you are not recreating the widget. Remove `_database.open();` from `_buildMessageHistory()`

Comment: I moved it to `build()` method but still same issues.

Comment: You need to move it to `init()` method of state or you can put it in `main()` and use it all over the app. You should use `await` and wait till the `db` initialization finishes.

Comment: By `init()`, did you mean `initState()` method?

Comment: Yes `initState()`

Comment: Did it fix the issue?

Comment: Yes, putting `_database.open()` to `initState()` didn't work. So I moved it to `list()` method itself and now it's working. I believe the `initState()` was not calling again on changing screen and `_database` instance was deleted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217205/discussion-between-sanjay-sharma-and-anuj-tbe).